# Анимация .hide() в jquery

Tags: jquery

Когда используешь

```
`.hide()`
```

или

```
.show()
```

в библиотеке jquery, то элементы всегда одинаково исчезают. А именно, уползают вверх-вправо. Как сделать другую анимацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `animate()`.

Comment: Благодарствую.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Так же на случай если - вниз и вверх:

```
slideDown()
slideUp()
```

И наоборот.